# JObject.Parse gives System.ArgumentNullException after working for a while

Tags: json.net

We have a weird problem with JSON.Net. Everything is working with our IIS application fine. At some point of the day JObject.Parse starts to give error. It works fine until that time. After that the parse fails.

The exception is:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
  at ASP.areas_admin_views_shared_editortemplates_reflectionfield_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
  ....
```

The code where it is called

```
  <% JObject o = JObject.Parse((string)ViewData["ReflectionField_Choices"].ToString()); %>
```

I have debugged this and following string works:

```
  { 'choices' : [{'Form_id' : 11065,'Fields' : [],'Name' : 'B'}] }
```

And following string fails:

```
  { 'choices' : [{'Form_id' : 11065,'Fields' : [{'ReflectionField_id' : 283860}],'Name' : 'B'}] }
```

The failing string of course works when everything is ok. Does anyone have any idea what could cause the change of this library during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I think, your problem might be that `ViewData["ReflectionField_Choices"]`is erased somewhere in the process. Might be because it's saved as ViewData and after some time (expiration of cookies/session)/refreshes the data is lost.

Comment: That was my first idea also. But I have debugged to the line in template and it really is there. I can also edit the template (because it does not restart the application) and it fails even if I give the failing string directly to the method.